# How to refresh GNOME Music?

Tags: music

Whenever I delete a track from my system, GNOME Music keeps it in my library. How do I refresh GNOME Music so it removes them from my library?

This problem doesn't seem to occur for mp3 tracks that don't have tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the GUI utility `tracker-preferences` to update relevant information.

`gnome-music` uses `tracker` to find your music.  The easiest way to interact with `tracker` is through the `tracker-preferences` utility.  From there, you can tell tracker to index certain directories.  This means we can solve the issue by "un-indexing" and "re-indexing" whatever directory holds your music.

1. Install `tracker-preferences`.  This may be as simple as `sudo dnf install tracker-preferences`, or `sudo apt-get install tracker-ui`, or you may have to figure out how to install it on your machine.
2. Open `tracker-preferences` either at the command line or through your applications menu.
3. Under the `Locations` tab, find the directory listing that has your music, e.g. `/home/username/Music`.  Un-check the radial button for `Recurse` on that directory.  Click the `Apply` button.  Re-check the radial for `Recurse` on the directory.  Click the `Apply` button again.  Wait for the `tracker` database to update.  (There's no output or loading bar or anything, just give it a minute or two to work in the background.)
4. Open `gnome-music` either from the command line or from your applications menu.  If tracker has been able to update, your library should reflect the changes.

I know this is more of a "sledgehammer" solution than I would prefer, but it's the only thing I've found to work.  Please feel free to update with other suggestions or workarounds.

---

Resources:

1. ["How to solve gnome-music “no music” issue on Fedora 20"](https://narmo7.wordpress.com/2014/04/10/how-to-solve-gnome-music-no-music-issue-on-fedora-20/)
2. `man tracker` & `tracker daemon help` and other help pages

Comment: is there any specific command for tracker to update the tracker database?

Comment: 2017: the package is called `tracker-gui` on ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

```
tracker index -m audio
```

Seems to work for me, but not sure if it is effected by the earlier clearing.
However the manual says that -m is to RE-index the mime parameter.

```
tracker status
```

will tell you when the process has finished, have about 3k music files in the assigned folder and it took about 4 minutes for the gnome-music albums and library to update.

Answer (score 1):

`tracker daemon -t` (terminate tracker daemons)

followed by

`tracker daemon -s` (start tracker daemons)

does the trick for me. Use `tracker status` to see how many files are added. If it doesn't work you might use `tracker reset --hard` first, this will delete the tracker index.